# Why is my Flutter Application is showing "App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist."

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing an ios app in flutter and firebase, when I run my app in visual studio code it shows the following in the terminal:-

```
5.20.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.swift, make sure  you've added the following in that order

```
FirebaseApp.configure() //add this before the code below
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

If you're using flutter with objective-c, add the following

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure]; //add this right after the above
```

Comment: where is the AppDelegate.swift file located in ????

Comment: ios\Runner\AppDelegate.swift

Comment: are you using the latest firebase packages? if so, the above step is not required

Comment: no i am using older packages....

Comment: hey ,there is only AppDelgate.m and AppDelgate.h located in the runner......where is it

Comment: It seems your ios project uses objective-c, I've updated the answer to reflect that. Also, it should be in AppDelegate.m